# UIPickerView With different row heights for same component swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview

Want to create UIPickerView with different row heights of single component. Is it possible to do that with UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate methods?

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 40
}
```

Comment: You could try to return different value based on different `component`

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that rowHeightForComponent is only called called once, and therefore there is no way to distinguish between specific rows. So this is unfortunately not possible.